# Page numbering isn't working

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to set numbers on the pages but it's not working properly. For example, it starts from the first page as 1, then the second page takes the number 2, then the third page takes the number 1, the forth page takes the number 1, the fifth the number 1 and so on.

The way I tried to numbering the pages was:

1. `Insert -> Page number -> Bottom page`
2. `Insert -> Footer -> Page number -> Bottom page`

But the result is the same. Also, I tried to remove all the footers and page numbers by selecting `Remove footers` and `Remove page numbers` and then re-adding the page numbers but again, the same issue.

When I use the Navigation panel, it shows the Page number. An example of what I mean:

[image: example]

Any idea why that might be? I cannot share the document because it is a paper to be published.

Microsoft Word version 2401 (Build 17231.20236 Click-to-Run), Windows 10.

Comment: Have you been inserting section breaks instead of page breaks?

Comment: Let me check that and if I did, I will remove them and I'll post the results here.

Comment: It seems that because I have a two column layout, and some images are capturing the whole, this creates the "section break issue" (the problem I showed above). Any recommendations on how can I solve this? The images cannot be placed on one column.

Comment: See http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm for an examination of what has been happening.

Comment: Nice webpage! It went straight to to the bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is while I was inserting page numbers, I had to go to select the page number (at the bottom of the page in my case) and then go to `page number` -> `Format page number` -> `Continue from previous page`.

[image: example]